# Quick CapsLock activation on Mac OS Ventura

Tags: macos, capslock, macos-ventura

I want Caps Lock to activate instantly when i press it. It seems, there is a bit of a longer activation time by default (have to keep my finger longer on the key).

Enabling slow keys, then setting the slider all the way to the left (shortest acceptance delay) works fine, but it breaks another thing: if i keep a letter pressed, the repetition is very slow, even if i set key repeat rate to fast and delay until repeat to the  shortest:

[Repeat rate and delay settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5M8A.png)

I would like fast caps lock activation and keep the key repeat feature as well, but it seems i cannot find the correct settings. Disabling the long press accented character popup thingy also did not help:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```